# Mongoose How to sort .populate field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm work with an user/articles profile system. I have been using the `.populate()` to render the posts but I cannot get the articles sorted by the date they were created.

I am using the `createdAt` variable as the main way of ordering the posts displayed.

For reference:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            req.flash("error", "something went wrong")
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    }).populate('articles')

    res.render('users/show',{
        user: user
    });
```

and the article.js:

```
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  author: {
    type: String
  },

  markdown: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  sanitizedHtml: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  img: {
    type: String
  },

  type:{
    type: String
  },

  user : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

}, {timestamps: true});
```

In advance thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called `options` in [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions),

```
.populate({
  path: 'articles',
  options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
})
```